# physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart issue

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm trying to use physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart function to implement a line of sight between player and enemy entities. However this function seems to be bugged.
here is my implementation:

```
let body :SKPhysicsBody! = aScene.physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart(enemy.spriteComponent.node.position, end: player.spriteComponent.node.position)

if body != nil {
    print ("playerPOS \(player.spriteComponent.node.position)")
    print ("enemyPOS \(enemy.spriteComponent.node.position)")
    print (body.node?.position)
}
```

On the console i get something like this:

```
playerPOS (220.463073730469, 368.627807617188)
enemyPOS (89.3868865966797, 457.411376953125)
(0.0, 0.0)
```

my question is how did it return a node that falls outside of the range of the ray?

Comment: sorry, typo. should be body != nil.

Comment: Do you a large sprite at (0, 0) or does the scene have a physics body?

Comment: Yes, the scene has a physicsbody. But I thought the function only returns a body that's along the ray between start to end position.

Comment: Try adding `view.showsPhysics = true` to `didMoveToView` to display an outline of all physics bodies in the scene.

Comment: I did that in the viewController along with show FPS and Node count. not sure what's that gonna help? I already made sure that all the walls have a physicsbody attached to them.

Comment: Do you have a node (with physics body) that isn't a direct child of the scene?

Comment: The walls are added to worldNode which is then added to the Scene. but the worldNode itself doesn't have any physics body.

Comment: A node's position is relative to its parent which may or may not be the scene. Try printing the position in scene coordinates by adding `let point = convertPoint(body.node!.position, fromNode:body.node!.parent!)` and `print (point)` to your `if` statement.

Comment: very strange i got the following error:  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: It looks like the node with the physics body is the scene because it's the only node without a parent (the cause of the crash). Try adding `print(body.node!)` before the `let point ...` statement. It will print information about the node. It should print something like `<SKScene> name:'(null)'...`

Comment: i know for sure it is the frame of the scene because i used  print(body?.categoryBitMask) to print the categoryBitMask which returned a number indicating the Frame of the scene

Comment: Do you know why the scene is being reported?

Comment: That is precisely what my question is. Lol. Why the frame of scene at 0,0 being returned when it is no where near/in the line/ray between player and enemy's position.

Comment: I suggest you post the code that creates the scene's physics body. Also, does the world node move and are the player and enemy added to the world node or scene?

Comment: I figured it out. Had to convert their locations to world locations first. Thanks for helping me along the way.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was going with my last comment. I'm glad you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. Since both player and enemy entities were added to a WorldNode I had to use aScene.convertPoint(location, fromNode: aScene.worldNode) to convert their locations and use the converted locations in the function physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart()

Thanks for all the helps along the way.